# Expressjs req.query not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to expressjs and this is my first work. I want `req.query` to return only rivers that have location of Africa. I don't get what I want instead it returns all the rivers in the database. This is my code:

**database**

```
var rivers = [
    {"name": "Nile", "location": "africa"},
    {"name": "Niger", "location": "africa"},
    {"name": "Indus", "location": "asia"},
    {"name": "Danube", "location": "europe"},
    {"name": "Thames", "location": "europe"},
    {"name": "Ohio", "location": "america"}
];
```

router

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.query.location);
});
```

`http://localhost:3000/rivers?location=africa`

Comment: Where are you using "database"? Your middleware doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: I think the OP means just data, which is that `rivers` Array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all the corresponding elements in your Array, based on the passed `req.query.location` and then `res.send` them back to your client.

Here's an example:

```
var rivers = [
  { "name": "Nile", "location": "africa" },
  { "name": "Niger", "location": "africa" },
  { "name": "Indus", "location": "asia" }
]

router.get('/rivers', function (req, res) {
  const matchingRivers = rivers.filter(river => {
    return river.location === req.query.location
  });

  res.send(matchingRivers);
});
```

and visit: `http://localhost:300/rivers?location=africa`.

Keep in mind:

- `req.query` holds the query parameters you are sending through with your URL.
- `res.send` sends something back to your client.

Comment: He said *all* the rivers that match 'africa'. So wouldn't Array.filter make more sense?.

Comment: I still get all the rivers in the array instead of just the rivers with location of 'africa'

Comment: That's because you are hitting the wrong endpoint. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I already had the endpoint set up here `router.use('/rivers', require('./rivers'));` . All other CRUD operations works for me except the query

Comment: From a first glance it looks you are very off base as to how Express works. Read the  documentation again, preferably from the very beginning. I really can't help you here.